# Replacing a missing month using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my output

```
[{ "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-SEP-14|0.59" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-MAY-14|0.87" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-NOV-14|0.25" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-JUL-14|0.67" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-DEC-14|0.10" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-OCT-14|0.03" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-DEC-14|0.14" }]
```

In this `ABC` has only data for 3 months `SEP, NOV, DEC` and `XYZ` has data for 4 months  `MAY, JUL, OCT, DEC`. I am trying to fetch data from this output. But I am getting a problem while implementing it because of the months. In `ABC` there are only 3 months and the other 9 months are missing. Same in the case of `XYZ` there are 4 months and the other 8 months are missing. I am trying to replace these missing months with that month and the corresponding value to 0.0.

For example in `ABC` OCT is missing between the months I am trying to replace with `01-OCT-14|0.0` similar with all the cases. For this I have written the below code but its not working. Please correct the code.

```
var data = new Array();
data = ' [{ "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-SEP-14|0.59" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-MAY-14|0.87" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-NOV-14|0.25" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-JUL-14|0.67" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-DEC-14|0.10" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-OCT-14|0.03" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-DEC-14|0.14" }]';    

var currentTime = new Date();//Sat Mar 21 2015 17:19:15 GMT+0530
var monthNames = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
var ctdate = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1; //Here I get the current month eg:MAR
var dynmonths = new Array();
dynmonths = monthNames.slice(ctdate).concat(monthNames.slice(0, ctdate));//Here I get previous 12 months for comparision 
//["APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC","JAN","FEB","MAR"];
var MFG_NAME = [];
var DATE = [];
var MKT = [];
```

//The code to replace the months starts here

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
var share = item.CONCATED_MKT_SHARE;
for (var j = 0; j < dynmonths.length; j++) {
        if (share.indexOf('-' + dynmonths[j] + '-') == -1) {
            share += ',01-' + dynmonths[j] + '-14|0.0';
        }
    }// The months are replaced at the end, instead I want to replace it in order of the month names
```

//This is my actual implementation code where I get the output arrays DATE and MKT

```
var share = item.CONCATED_MKT_SHARE;    
var parts = share.split("|");
var i = MFG_NAME.indexOf(item.MFG_NAME);
if (i == -1) {
    MFG_NAME.push(item.MFG_NAME);
    DATE.push([parts.shift()]);
    MKT.push([+parts.shift()]);
}
else {
    DATE[i].push(parts.shift());
    MKT[i].push(+parts.shift());
}
```

});

I am getting the DATE and MKT but I am not getting the missing months

Expected output

```
 DATE[0] = ["01-APR-14","01-MAY-14","01-JUN-14","01-JUL-14","01-AUG-14","01-SEP-14","01-OCT-14","01-NOV-14","01-DEC-14","01-JAN-14","01-FEB-14","01-MAR-14"];

DATE[1] = ["01-APR-14","01-MAY-14","01-JUN-14","01-JUL-14","01-AUG-14","01-SEP-14","01-OCT-14","01-NOV-14","01-DEC-14","01-JAN-14","01-FEB-14","01-MAR-14"];

MKT[0] = ["0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.0","0.59","0.0","0.25","0.10","0.0","0.0","0.0"];

MKT[1] = [""0.0","0.75","0.0","0.67","0.0","0.0","0.03","0.0","0.14"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd already started when @Learning posted his answer, so I just finished for an alternate take.

http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/ah4c0oah/3/

```
var data = [
    { "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-SEP-14|0.59" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-MAY-14|0.87" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-NOV-14|0.25" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-JUL-14|0.67" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-DEC-14|0.10" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-OCT-14|0.03" },
    { "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-DEC-14|0.14" }
];

var monthNames = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];

var DATES = [[], []];
var MARKETS = [[], []];

function findDataForMonth(mfgName, month) {
    for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
        var datum = data[i];

        if (datum.MFG_NAME === mfgName && datum.CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.indexOf(month) >= 0) {
            return datum.CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.split('|')[1];
        }
    }
}

var monthsToCheck = [];

function addMonthsForYear(year, minMonth, maxMonth) {
    for (var i = 0, length = monthNames.length; i < length; i++) {
        if ((!minMonth || i >= minMonth) && (!maxMonth || i <= maxMonth)) {
            monthsToCheck.push('01-' + monthNames[i] + '-' + year);
        }
    }
}

var monthOffset = new Date().getMonth();

addMonthsForYear(12, monthOffset);
addMonthsForYear(13);
addMonthsForYear(14);
addMonthsForYear(15, undefined, monthOffset);

for (var i = 0, length = monthsToCheck.length; i < length; i++) {
    var month = monthsToCheck[i];

    MARKETS[0].push(findDataForMonth("ABC", month) || 0.0);
    MARKETS[1].push(findDataForMonth("XYZ", month) || 0.0);

    DATES[0].push(month);
    DATES[1].push(month);
}

console.log(DATES);
console.log(MARKETS);
```

Comment: This is awesome and correct. But your starting it from JAN. instead can you show it starting from the currentmonth-12 to current month. I will tell you more clearly suppose this month is MAR can I show the data starting from APR 2014 to MAR 2015(i.e last 12 months based on currentdate) or from MAR 2015 to APR 2014. Because that is the requirement. I must show previous values based on current month

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to add an outer for-loop for the year(s) range and pick a month starting point. I'll try to update the example before I have to leave. (Lunch soon!)

Comment: one more doubt. When you put alert alert ending for loop for DATE[0] or DATE[1] the months are coming in order but after 01-DEC-2014 the next month must be 01-JAN-2015. But here in your code it is 01-JAN-2014

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Check the console on the link I attached. The month's ordering is `[..."01-DEC-14", "01-JAN-15"...]`.

Comment: I have seen in the console but now the date is between 01-MAR-12 ... 01-MAR-15 :(

Comment: You're capable of editing the sample code I've provided. I'm not a for-hire dev here. I provided help. I think you can probably piece together what remains. :)

Comment: OK sorry. and thanq :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution, You can try this

```
var i=0;
for(var jo in pdata)
{
    DATE.push([]);
    MKT.push([]);
    for(var mnt in monthNames)
    {
        var index = pdata[jo].m.indexOf("01-"+monthNames[mnt]+"-14");
        if(index<0)
        {
            DATE[i].push("01-"+monthNames[mnt]+"-14");
            MKT[i].push("0.0");
        }
        else{
            DATE[i].push(pdata[jo].m[index]);
            MKT[i].push(pdata[jo].v[index]);
        }
    }
    i++;
}

var element = "";
for(i=0;i<DATE.length;i++)
{
    element += DATE[i].join(", ");
    element += "<br/>";
    element += MKT[i].join(", ");
    element += "<br/>";
}
```

Please check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramfv75z/3/)